# load a website in webview

Tags: android

I created an xml file contains a webview.

I hope to load http://www.google.com in this webview

How can I do it?

Comment: did you really copy paste the code exactly or not from the official example. If yes then describe the scenario to more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add permission for accessing Internet in your Manifest file as shown below,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

add the above line, before application tag beins

Answer (score 0):

It's funny because the **official example** uses Google as the test page:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Comment: May be you not add Internet permission @ AndroidMenifeast

Answer (score 0):

try this

webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

Comment: the problem is WebPage not available