# firefox do not send the header : if-modified-since after receive Last-modified from the response

Tags: http-status-code-304

firefox do not send the header : if-modified-since after receive Last-modified from the response.
eg: 
visiting [load a website in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066087/load-a-website-in-webview) in Firefox, and after several times load this page，press F12，in the console show below screenshot.

```
Response :
Age 123613
Cache-Control   public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length  93868
Content-Type    text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 16 Mar 2012 04:17:48 GMT
Expires Thu, 24 May 2012 14:47:48 GMT
Last-Modified   Wed, 23 Nov 2011 21:10:59 GMT
Server  sffe
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Via 1.1 HSPROXY08
Warning 113 HSPROXY08  
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block

Request:
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language zh-cn,zh;q=0.5
Host    ajax.googleapis.com
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Referer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066087/load-a-website-in-webview
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

I find there is no "if-modified-since" in request header, that's why?

and I thought the response status code should be 304,but it is 200.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

before sending your 304 header,

1/ you need to send the same exact headers (except for the date  & expires values obviously) you've sent with the file the first time in the exact same order

2/ you add a `'Content-Length:0'` header

then you send that 304 header and then you're good.